# How to save different images into different directories in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, mkdir

I want to save 4 images in 4 directories and name of directories are 4,5,6,7 (for instance image 1 in directory 4 and image 2 in directory 5 and so on) but it seems my for loop it's not correct and just saves the last image in directory 4.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

pixels = 600
my_dpi = 100
num_geo=3

coord = np.array([[[-150, -200], [300, -200], [300, 0], [150, 200], [-150, 200]],
                  [[-300, -200], [200, -300], [200, -50], [200, 300], [-150, 200]],
                  [[-140, -230], [350, -260], [350, 0], [140, 200], [-180, 220]],
                  [[-180, -240], [370, -270], [370, 0], [170, 200], [-190, 230]]])

for i in range(4):
    geo = coord[i, :, :]
    print(coord[i])
    fig = plt.figure(num_geo,figsize=( pixels/my_dpi,  pixels/my_dpi),facecolor='k', dpi=my_dpi)  
    plt.axes([0,0,1,1])
    rectangle = plt.Rectangle((-300, -300), 600, 600, fc='k')
    plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)
    polygon = plt.Polygon(coord[i],color='w')
    plt.gca().add_patch(polygon)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.axis([-300,300,-300,300])
for j in range(4,8):  
    os.mkdir("fig/%d" % j)
    plt.savefig('fig/%d/%d.jpg' % (j,i), dpi=my_dpi)
    plt.close()
```

Comment: you don't need `for j in range(4,8):`. Use `savefig` in loop  `for i in range(4):`  and use `j = i+4` in file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need second loop - besides it runs after first loop when `i` has value `4` so you get all images in directory `4`

You need `j = i + 4`

```
for i in range(4):
    geo = coord[i, :, :]
    print(coord[i])
    fig = plt.figure(num_geo,figsize=( pixels/my_dpi,  pixels/my_dpi),facecolor='k', dpi=my_dpi)  
    plt.axes([0,0,1,1])
    rectangle = plt.Rectangle((-300, -300), 600, 600, fc='k')
    plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)
    polygon = plt.Polygon(coord[i],color='w')
    plt.gca().add_patch(polygon)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.axis([-300,300,-300,300])
    j = i + 4
    os.mkdir("fig/%d" % j)
    plt.savefig('fig/%d/%d.jpg' % (j,i), dpi=my_dpi)
    plt.close()
```